# How to fix damaged door frame

Tags: door-frame, damage

[[image: pic of damage][1]]Heavy winds caught my storm door and tore the bottom arm out of the wall, taking a chunk of the board attached to it. It appears to be an easy fix by just replacing the board that is damaged, but I wanted to ask if that really is all that would need to be done. Seems too easy and I've never had this issue before. Any insight on the easiest way to fix it would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked on here ?

Comment: The hard part is matching the paint, but that is one way.  It looks like a nice clean break, so a bit of good wood glue might be enough.  Finishing nails/small screws to hold it till the glue cures.

Comment: I have looked on here, just haven't found anything specific enough to my situation. I  think wood glue would likely suffice, my only concern is if it would create a strong enough bond and not come loose again later?

Comment: Could probably glue it back together, the hard part is clamping until the glue dries. You need to clamp with a _lot_ more pressure than most people think to get a good glue joint. You can use screws to hold it once it's clamped tightly. Maybe if pilot holes are drilled prior to gluing you  might get it tight enough to get a good glue joint that will withstand the door closer pulling on it. Could remount the closer to the top of the door, though...

Comment: There is a closer at the top of the door as well so maybe the bottom one isn't even needed? I'm considering using wood glue and drilling some longer screws in to secure it. I also have some 50LB weights that I can place against to hold it tight against the wall until it dries.. Would that work?

Comment: If done right, a glue joint should be stronger than the wood.  Glue is used for wooden wing spars on planes.

Comment: Polyurethane glue like Gorilla Glue and PVA glue like Titebond do not tolerate any gaps. The polyurethane glue's foaming suggests that it does, but it doesn't. If the fit up could be poor, then you want to use an epoxy (epoxy does tolerate gaps). A little tube sufficient for this job isn't terribly expensive. As an added bonus, it sets up fast enough where you could potentially take the time to stand there holding the thing together. Definitely use the longer screws to grab into a stronger substrate material.

Comment: Understood, i think im going to go with the Poly glue and the longer screws. I really appreciate all the comments. I'll be back if something goes wrong!

Comment: If there's a 1/32" gap with polyurethane glue, then you may as well have used spray foam for the repair. Be sure to get some clamping pressure and fit that break back together very well.

Comment: @crip659, PVA and polyurethane glues aren't used in plane spars, though. That sounds like a resorcinol or epoxy application.

Comment: @popham  I forget the type of glue used 40 years ago, but do remember the break repair needed a 15 to 1 slope made.

Comment: @crip659, there's something: https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_43.13-1B_w-chg1.pdf. PDF page 38 (1-4 under their pagination). Looks like a specification-qualified yes for resorcinol and a vaguely qualified yes for epoxy. My understanding was that ideally you want a slow setting epoxy so that it has time to penetrate into the wood, but I'm surprised to not see any language like that. My understanding is actually contradicted by their passive mention of epoxies with short pot life. Maybe there's some kind of chemical additive that improves wood penetration.

Answer (score 1):

When you remount the closer, use screws long enough to go through the trim and into the actual door frame -- or, for rock-solid, use 3" or 3.5"  screws that will go all the way to the stud, as we would for serious lock strikes.

Answer (score 0):

Use epoxy adhesive to glue the wood back together. You can stand there holding it for 5 minutes to avoid dealing with fasteners for the trim repair. It's also more forgiving for imperfect fit ups and near-zero pressure.

For the closer, drill a pilot hole through the trim and fasten into the wall's framing. Implement the same pattern for the top closer to avoid future issues there.